# I am having [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Error even if my colors is (100%) right

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have a buttons in SpriteKit that created with array of colors:

```
let buttonColors : [UIColor] = [
        UIColor(red: 202/255.0, green: 71/255.0, blue: 118/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 107/255.0, green: 107/255.0, blue: 175/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 139/255.0, green: 222/255.0, blue: 213/255.0, alpha: 1.0), ]
```

When I run the app I get this message in console:

> [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the
>   expected range. Set a breakpoint on
>   UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will
>   only be logged once.

I am setting the breakpoint as suggested and it stops on initialization with one of my randomly chosen (from array) colors, howerver the color looks right:
[image: This is my color and everything looks right]

There is a numerous of questions regarding this error and seems like all of them is because people use values like 245.0 instead of 245/255.0 or 0.95. So thought that maybe my case and I miss /255 somewhere or mess with numbers, i tripple check everything and everything seems okay. So i didn't believed myself and tried to change my colors array to this:

```
let buttonColors : [UIColor] = [
        UIColor.green,
        UIColor.red,
        UIColor.blue,
        UIColor.black,
        UIColor.white,
        UIColor.magenta,
        UIColor.cyan,
        UIColor.yellow
        ]
```

And - still the same! 
I have rebooted, deleted app and clean build folder and all looks the same. Any thought where to put my attention with that? Thank you!

Comment: Create a new project and add only your colors array init. See if you get the same error / warning. If so, maybe you've got something funky in your Xcode installation? If not, do you have any `UIColor` **extensions** in your code? Something else that might be affecting it?

Comment: @DonMag I am using this framework which giving this error - https://github.com/efremidze/Magnetic - If I am trying example code it still give me this error. There is a UIColor extension in this code (that doesn't look wrong) but even if I am not using this extensions all looks the same. Also this happens both in xcode 9 or xcode 10 beta and have tried on different machine as well. Walking through the example code and didn't find anything related.

Comment: @DonMag - also all xcode installations is just apple downloaded one without any extensions installed or anything

Comment: @DonMag - and one more thing - even if I am using same color everytime (UIColor.red for example) - the error and breakpoint doesn't fire everytime, can be everytime, can be 4 without and fire on the fifth without any noticeable pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is a great answer, but it doesn't really fit in a comment, so...

I grabbed "[Magnetic](https://github.com/efremidze/Magnetic)" that you linked to and ran the Example app on `Simulator iPhone 7 / 11.3`

Ran it completely as-is - no code editing at all. Ran it again, and again, and again, and... 5th time I got the *"far outside the expected range"* message.

So, I commented-out their `UIColor` extension and replaced:

```
let color = UIColor.colors.randomItem()
```

with:

```
let color = UIColor.blue
```

resulting in, of course, 12 blue "bubbles".

Ran it, ran it, ran it, and... got the *"far outside the expected range"* message again.

So, I don't think it has anything to do with your `buttonColors`. My guess - some odd internal bug with SpriteKit? I haven't done any real work with SpriteKit, so I don't have any other code to try to replicate this.

Google searching hasn't found me anything other than the usual dev errors (using `241` instead of `241.0 / 255.0`).

I also don't see any mention of it in the Magnetic issues.

Since it's just a "warning" message, and since you are getting the correct colors, unless you want to contact Apple with a Technical Support Incident (TSI), maybe just let it go? Or open an issue with the authors of Magnetic?

Comment: Not sure if it is 100% legit to do that here but I think this IS an answer, thank you very much for digging in, I also think this can be some internal stuff going on - but this is always good to have one more opinion. Also I have searched here and somewhere else on the internet there was a couple times where doing 0.33 or 245/255 things not resolving the issue so it can be same thing there. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I was also having this issue and was absolutely sure I was not using illegal values, which led me to this SO question. Destiny seems to be at work, as I am not just also using SpriteKit, I am using Magnetic! There must be something weird going on within Magnetic, or SpriteKit has some asinine weird bug resulting in us all ending up at the same StackOverflow page.